# Rails `link_to` - Adding custom HTML5 property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

How do I add [RDFa Lite 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-lite/#vocab-typeof-and-property) `property="url"` to my Rails `link_to`?

`<%= link_to "Lipsum", my_path, property: "url" %>`, naturally, won't work.

Desired outcome:

`<a href="/my/path" property="url">Lipsum</a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html

```
<%= link_to "Lipsum", my_path, { property: "url" } %>
```

In console:

```
irb(main):011:0> ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to('test', advisors_path, { property: 'url' })
=> "<a property=\"url\" href=\"/advisors\">test</a>"
```

Comment: By the way man, any chance you're up for hire for a short gig?

Comment: @MarkBoulder Always interested in opportunities. Feel free to email me tomfast at gmail.